# Excel 2003 ListBox Type Mismatch when calling a sub

Tags: vba

Here's a Sub at the Workbook level:

```
Public Sub BuildList(targetSheet As Worksheet, ByRef targetListBox As ListBox, lastRow As Integer)

    For r = 1 To lastRow

        If Trim(targetSheet.Range("A" & r).Value) <> "" Then

            With targetListBox

                .AddItem Trim(targetSheet.Range("A" & r).Value)
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = Trim(targetSheet.Range("B" & r))

            End With

        End If

    Next r


End Sub
```

Here's some code in a Userform that calls it:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim bottomRow As Integer

    Set ws = Worksheets("Our Status Code")
    bottomRow = ws.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    ThisWorkbook.BuildList ws, StatusCodesListbox, bottomRow


End Sub
```

When it hits the line that calls BuildList it throws an error 13 and I can't see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
 ByRef targetListBox As MSForms.ListBox
```

There are two types of listbox for Excel.